# Using threads in iPhone, do i need them in this case?

Tags: iphone

I have an opengl game, on top of it i am placing an small view that connects to the internet, retrieves data, with part of that data it connects again to retrieve an image and then displays it inside the view.

All this calls are asynchronous. Do i have to also use threads? What should i put inside in another thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, NSURLRequest is asyncronous, you just say what delegate it should use when receiving data and take it from there :-) No need for more threads to handle that